# Recurrence Information is wrong when changed in editor

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

When editing an Appointment in Outlook for the Web, the Add-In will always get the same recurrence information for an item while it is open. When queried the first time the information seems to be accurate. The second time it is still the same even if the actual recurrence of the appointment was changed.

We're in the appointment compose case and use the `getAsync()` function to get the recurrence.

Comment: We are unable to reproduce this issue inhouse. Can you please share your code-snippet with us?

Comment: I've an update here. This seems to be occurring only before the item is actually saved for the first time. After saving the appointment and reopening it for editing it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. It has been put on our backlog. We unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point